# Dimension and fact table creating in Pentaho from single SQL table(source table)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, pentaho, create-table

I have one CSV file, has all info, I converted all info into the one table and stored it in MySQL.
It has many fields.
What is the best approach to create a table like this:
How can I set the auto-increment primary key for my table and how can I get a unique name from the source table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would typically create a table with an auto_incremented primary key, and then feed it using `select distinct`:

```
create table disticts(
    district_id int auto_increment primary key,
    district_name varchar(100)
);

insert into disticts (district_name)
select distinct district_name from mytable
```

Comment: Which objects can I use in the Pentaho spoon to perform these SQL steps?

First step: table input
2 insert/update
3. table output

like this??